# how to include sqlite4java in android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to use sqlite4java in my android project. the following screenshot shows my project's setup:

[image: My Project setup]

As you can see i have copied the jar-file into my libs folder and included it in the build path. I have also copied the docs and the src-file as per the docs for sqlite4java. The zip-file i downloaded also contains a library-file called `libsqlite4java-android-i686.so`that i included in the libs directory. what i get when i try to run my project (it will compile without complaining) is the follwing error message:

```
03-04 07:37:13.251: W/System.err(2419): 
com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sqlite4java-android-i686 
from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data
/app/de.redhouse24.android-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data
/app-lib/de.redhouse24.android-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned 
null
```

As you can see the file `sqlite4java-android-i686.so`cannot be found. Being wiley, i renamed the `libsqlite4java-andriod-i686.so` file to `sqlite4java-android-i686.so`, which is why my project structure shows that name for the file. TBH, i renamed it because i found the suggestion in this discussion:
https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/issues/detail?id=42

I also tried to include the so-file in the build path, but that just stopped my project from compiling.

My question: What do i need to do to use sqlite4java in my android project?

Im using a mac and eclipse with adt, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Why exactly are you using sqlite4java, when there's native sqlite support within android's framework? If there is no specific requirement, consider using android's implementation of sqlite.

Comment: @Mjoellnir - its a project requirement to be able to reuse existing code, unfortunately.

Comment: @DerGolem - i tried that, it doesnt work. also the getting started guide explicitly says to put the the zip-files and the library file in the same folder as the jar file

Comment: try adding the libraries to the build path. Check if that helps. Though android itself has SQLite

Comment: Put it under `libs/x86/libsqlite4java.so` -- don't forget to include modules for ARM when you go into production.

Comment: Try this version posted here :
 [libsqlite4java-android-i686](https://sqlite4java.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=420009000&name=libsqlite4java-android-i686.so&token=ABZ6GAf8_YbCc5BkaC5sx5Ar_YbtkPzdVg%3A1425489124818)

Comment: @Mjoellnir - thanks for the comment. i figured renaming the so-file wouldnt be too smart, but i was getting desperate. For the location of the docs and sources i was following these instructions: https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/wiki/GettingStarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, renaming the library will not help you. Do not rename the library, leave the name as it was.

Second, you only have the 686-lib there. 
If you intent to run your app on something other than an atom-based device, you will have to add the so-files for the other architectures as well.
Each architecture's so-files resides in a sub-directory under the libs directory, like this:

```
libs/x86
libs/armeabi
libs/armeabi-v7a
```

Put your libsqlite4java-android-i686.so file there, and also possible other .so files it might need as a dependency, and it should work.

Including the sources and docs into the libs-folder somewhat eludes me. That will only bloat your final apk file, which should be avoided. 
Your users will be thankful.

Comment: that was it! thank you. how did you know about the subfolders? i couldnt find anything about that on the entire internet...

Comment: Well, I am working a lot with NDK stuff. It's documented in the Android NDK, and when you create your own NDK libraries, you'll also see these folders being created by the NDK's build process.